# pebble autoescape json - unicode entities

Tags: pebble

when I use

```
{% autoescape "json" %}
{
    "key" : "hellü"
}
{% endautoescape %}
```

the result is

```
{
    "key" : "hell\u00FC"
}
```

But I dont want the strings encoded to unicode entities when I'm already creating a utf8 text file with this json string in it - it is just unneeded and unwanted.

The result should just be this:

```
{
    "key" : "hellü"
}
```

Any idea how to disable unicode entities in escape json function?

Answer (score 0):

When you see the `\u` representation - that is escaping (not entities). So by using `autoescape` you escaped the json and that is good practice
[to avoid XSS variabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

If you still want to disable the autoEscaping you can do:

```
PebbleEngine engine = new PebbleEngine.Builder().autoEscaping(false).build();
```

For the full documentation: https://pebbletemplates.io/wiki/guide/escaping/

Comment: Hi, sorry but I'm not fully agreeing. I see a difference between JSON control character escape and unicode escape/entities (escape/entities... for me the same). I think it has to be looked seperately. umlauts and other unicode characters, which are no control character in json (unicode character like üäöáâè) can be clearly written in a utf8 json as plain unicode character. control characters like " ' { [ etc. has to be escaped by RFC standard, JSON text not by force: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-7 section 7 and 8